# How do we access databricks job parameters inside the attached notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, aws-databricks, dbutils, databricks-workflows

In Databricks if I have a job request json as:

```
{
  "job_id": 1,
  "notebook_params": {
    "name": "john doe",
    "age": "35"
  }
}
```

How do I access the notebook_params inside the job attached notebook?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In notebooks, you can access parameters via [Widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html)  using the [dbutils.widgets.get function](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#get-command-dbutilswidgetsget).  For your example, it will be:

```py
name = dbutils.widgets.get("name")
age = dbutils.widgets.get("age")
```

Please note that by default the value is string, so if you need to have `age` as number, you need to convert it.

Also, if you want to debug output before you put it as a job, then you need to declare corresponding widgets using one of the [`dbutils.widgets` functions](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#widgets-utility-dbutilswidgets), otherwise you'll get error that widget isn't defined when doing `dbutils.widgets.get`. For example, you can use `dbutils.widgets.text` that allows to enter any text):

```py
dbutils.widgets.text("name", "<default_name>", "Enter name")
dbutils.widgets.text("name", "<default_age>", "Enter age")
```

Comment: Let's say that I do not know the parameters names, on the example above: "name" or "age". Is there a way I can read the parameters without their name? I am building a function to read all the parameters procedurally. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what this means? "Also, if you want to debug output before you put it as a job"

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that is useful when you want to read all the parameters without having to define each single one of them.

```py
def get_parameters():
    
    all_args = dict(dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getCurrentBindings())

    # remove '--' substring
    all_args = {key.replace('--', ''): value for key, value in all_args.items()}

    # parse values to correct format
    all_args = {key: ast.literal_eval(value) for key, value in all_args.items()}

    return all_args
```

Be aware, you will only be able to get the parameters if you are running the notebook through a Job.

Comment: please note that `dbutils.notebook.entry_point` is internal function that could be removed at any point of time